# Different Minhagim of Terua Sounds

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

I recently heard that a difference exists between the terua sounds of different communities, i.e. Ashkenazim, Sepharadim and Temanim. What are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

I never knew that there was a difference regarding *teru'ah* sounding, just for *shevarim*. But, I located [this article](http://www.shofarot.com/index.php/the-shofar/shofarsounds/) that says

> The Teruah is (according to Rabbi Yitzhak Arama) the sign of anxiety
>   and sorrow. It is composed of more and shorter units than the
>   Shavarim. The Ashkenazi Jews produce Staccato-like, rhythmical units,
>   while the Oriental Jews produce a kind of wavy tremolo, composed on a
>   long sound (like a chain). Normally, in order to produce the long
>   tone’s vibrations, the Shofar blower uses his tongue.

Comment: What about temanim?

Comment: @147zcbm _ I don't know, offhand, but, I'll see what I might discover.

Comment: @147zcbm I did a Google Books search using the term "Yemenite Teruah". One of the results gave a synopsis of what is in Art Scrol Mishnah Mo'ed p. 105, that seems to say that the Yemenites sound teruah as 3 short groans. However, since the book gives a snippet, I can't completely determine what it says. Mayeb within the next few days, I can locate this book in my shul and see if I can edit what it says in my answer. If you locate it before me, feel free to update my answer. Shanah Tovah.

Comment: @DanF IIRC from some years ago, this wavy Teruah is that of the Geonim (or Jaonim) and is practiced by Yemenites. (Again not so sure about this).

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQtwIwBWoVChMIkurYuMDcxwIVQ9geCh10sgDT&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJtm1gSUekwg&usg=AFQjCNGlNAzuqaTcaTWEO6Sylu7coxnKtA&bvm=bv.101800829,d.dmo) haven't followed it. purports to be Temani shofar.